# Extent of Reference to Parameters in the Axiom of Separation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, first-order-logic

I'm trying to understand how and to what extent parameters are allowed to be used in the ZF axiom of separation with parameters. For example, if $\mathcal{M}$ is a ZF-structure, with domain $M$, $A\subset M$ is arbitrary, and $\phi$ is a formula with 2 variables, then is the following a valid form of the axiom?
$$\mathcal{M}\models\exists y\forall x\, x\in y\leftrightarrow \forall a\,\phi(x,a)\wedge a\in A\wedge x\in V_\omega$$ I know that part of my confusion stems from looking a various definitions and trying to determine when the word "set" refers to a subset of a structure's domain vs. a set defined in the language of set theory (assuming that I phrased that concept right). Specifically, is any form of quantification allowed to be applied just over the parameters? Or rather, for each instance of the schema, the finite selection of parameters is fixed.

Comment: What you wrote in your example is a *second-order* separation that is not what usual Separation intended. Parameters in Separation must be in the domain in the model, so in your case, $A$ must be an element of $\mathcal{M}$.